# How to display a logo in a printed web page that doesn't appear on-screen?

Tags: php, javascript, print

I have sales report I want to print with a logo, but I don't want it shown on the screen.

I'm currently trying to use JavaScript to print a particular DIV from a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
  function PrintDiv() {    
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + 
      divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="PrintDiv();">Print page</a>
```

Is this the right method I should use so that the logo is shown only in the printed sales report?

Comment: Questions about implementation are best asked at http://stackoverflow.com/ and are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Use a print stylesheet to show the logo.

Leave the logo in your on-screen version of the report, just hide that div with your normal stylesheet.

In your print stylesheet, simply display the div with the logo.

Here's a short, snappy guide to using a print stylesheet: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

Comment: Did you mean to include a link there...?

Comment: Sure did - sorry! added now!